# How do I keep printing after the user has given the input?

Tags: python-3.x, math, random

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import random


num_1 = random.choice(range(12))
num_2 = random.choice(range(12))
score = 0

start = timer()


end = timer()


t = (end - start) # Time in seconds, e.g. 5.38091952400282


    
if t < 5 : 
    score += 100
if t > 5 :
    score += 50

print(score)
```

how do i print the input again???

like after i have written what is 6 * 8 for example it gives me the score. How do i ask users for the question again???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the input inside the while loop:

```
num_1 = random.choice(range(12))
num_2 = random.choice(range(12))
score = 0

start = timer()


end = timer()


t = (end - start) # Time in seconds, e.g. 5.38091952400282

while True:
    
    ans = input("what is "+num1" * "+num2+"?")
    if t < 5 : 
        score += 100
    if t > 5 :
        score += 50

print(score)
```